# passing a string to open command in mac

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I want to pipe a string to the `open` command in zsh terminal.

this command: `open https://www.google.com` open the web-browser correctly.

However, running this command: `echo https://www.google.com | open` does not work. What's the correct way to pipe a string to this command?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can see from the [Man Page](https://ss64.com/osx/open.html) the open command does not take input from stdin so piping into it does not make much sense, but your syntax for piping is correct. You probably want to pass the result of echo as an argument. 
Try:

```sh
open $(echo https://www.google.com)
```